# Qt Qfile error. Can't find file or directory

Tags: qt

I am using Qt5.4.2 and I am getting an include error when trying to include Qfile. It is present in my include directory in the Qtcore folder. I cannot figure out how to solve this problem

```
#include "results.h"
#include "ui_results.h"
#include <QtCore/QFile>
#include <Qfile>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QMessageBox>

Results::Results(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Results)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    Qfile file("//home//baigoo365//Proj");

    if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
        QMessageBox::information(0, "info", file.errorString());

    QTextStream in(&file);

    ui->textBrowser->setText(in.readAll());

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's `#include <QFile>`. Not `#include <Qfile>`.

Comment: Same `Qfile file`. Other tip: And he used `#include <QtCore/QFile>` and `#include <Qfile>` at the same time. +1 for you answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your OS is Linux, than your include path is wrong, but if you are on Windows than not the include path is wrong, but your using of `QFile`:

```
Qfile file("//home//baigoo365//Proj");
```

You shall write this (with uppercase 'F'):

```
QFile file("//home//baigoo365//Proj");
```

But of course as the others says one include is enough :).